# fast backup script in linux

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, backup-restoration, incremental-backup

I have a server with more applications and do normal shell command to take backups. it took couple of days to complete. Tried to install duplicity. but its told some packages are not found. its Debian 2.6 in server.

Is there is decent industry standard script which will just sync the directory structure and zipped versions of files through to S3, but which just adds incremental changes (new and changed files)?

Comment: There are many scripts that will send files to S3. Which ones has your research turned up so far? You can also sync using dropbox or BitTorrent Sync, both are easy. Remember sync is not a backup, you'll want to use a backup program and sync its database. I use Attic.

Comment: Hi Tim,
Yes i tried this and get no attic package in servere then tried with another server (ubuntu). but here see  "no module named attic.chunker" when initiated it. can u pls help?

Comment: You'd need to provide far more precise information about error messages and what you tried. I just followed this guide, I don't know much beyond that http://ask.xmodulo.com/install-python3-centos.html